# "Where did you go" or "where have you gone"?

Tags: questions, phrase-choice

> Where did you go?

Or

> Where have you gone?

A person I am talking to suddenly goes offline, so I ask them: "Where did you go/where have you gone?"

As far as I think, 
"Where have you gone?" implies that the person is still not there and "Where as where did you go?" sounds like the person has returned.

I think I should say "Where have you gone?" Right?

Answer (score 2):

If the person leaves but does not return, and you call them on their phone:

> Where have you gone?
>
> Where did you go?

If the person leaves and then returns:

> Where did you go?
>
> Where have you been?

Comment: Where did you go work in both cases?

Comment: Yes, **Where did you go?** will work in both scenarios. The listener on the phone will understand that what the speaker is really asking is "Where are you *now*?"  The present perfect makes that meaning clearer, but the context is simple enough that there is very little room for misunderstanding even with the simple past.

Answer (score 1):

**Where have you gone?** represents a present perfect verb tense. As the man leaves the web presently so it should be used. **Where did you go?**  is a simple past tense which means the person goes somewhere in the past which is a bit incorrect here as you are referring a present time frame.